# Why might Spatial Join appear to produce incorrect values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

I'm trying to do a spatial join of a point file (created from a raster) to a polygon (target), where I am joining the GRID_CODE value from the point to the polygon. I've tried a variety of permutations, one-to-many, many-to-one, changing the order of the input files, putting in a mode and mean condition for field_map, checking the field properties (both Double), trying a multi-part to single-part conversion (data management) for both inputs, but the resulting joined field is always populated with incorrect data (as verified by looking at the point values).

For example, here is a screenshot of the correct values from the point file, highlighting the 2 (green)[image]

Here is a screenshot of the spatial join output highlighting that same 2 value, which I would expect to be in the same location.[image]

What is additionally bizarre, and might be a clue as to what is going on, is that the same field (GRID_CODE) has a different number of values (4 in the original, and 5 in the output[image]

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely to be due to the merge rules you are using (field map, right click field, merge rule).

[Merge rules](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00210000000s000000) are at the bottom of this page.

Try setting the rule to mode to assign the polygon with the value of the most common GRID_CODE.

Comment: interesting this worked when I did the right click method, but when i went in via the "+" sign and assigned the same condition (which then appeared as a sub-condition under fieldmap>gridcode, it didn't work. thanks!